# Accumulating values in an xmacro

Tags: c++

Given a definition like this (which I can change):

```
#define NUMERIC_FIELD_LIST \
FIELD(temperatureCalibrationFactor, float, TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR, getTemperatureCalibrationFactor, setTemperatureCalibrationFactor) \
FIELD(temperatureCalibrationOffset, float, TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_OFFSET_ADDR, getTemperatureCalibrationOffset, setTemperatureCalibrationOffset) \
FIELD(humidityCalibrationFactor,    float, HUMIDITY_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR,    getHumidityCalibrationFactor,    setHumidityCalibrationFactor)    \
FIELD(humidityCalibrationOffset,    float, HUMIDITY_CALIBRATION_OFFSET_ADDR,    getHumidityCalibrationOffset,    setHumidityCalibrationOffset)    \
```

I'm trying to use an xmacro to produce code that looks like this:

```
static const int TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR = 0
static const int TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_OFFSET_ADDR = TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR + sizeof(temperatureCalibrationOffset);  
static const int HUMIDITY_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR    = TEMPERATURE_CALIBRATION_OFFSET_ADDR + sizeof(humidityCalibrationFactor); 
static const int HUMIDITY_CALIBRATION_OFFSET_ADDR    = HUMIDITY_CALIBRATION_FACTOR_ADDR    + sizeof(humidityCalibrationOffset);
```

Notice that each item refers to a value defined in the previous line.  The obvious (and fragile) solution is to put the name of the previous item into the xmacro definition itself, but that seems a last resort (and maintaining the target code manually may even be preferable).

I've tried some creative ideas, like using a dummy struct and the offsetof macro, but that pads my sizes out to multiples of 4, which I don't want.

For a tiny bit of context, the constants I'm trying to create will be used for what are essentially byte positions in a tightly packed stream.  In that context, a char will occupy only one byte, even though in memory it may occupy 4.

The other consideration is that I am working in a resource-constrained environment, so I want the offsets to be computed at compile-time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is an *xmacro*?  Question 2: why are favoring macros rather than an inline function.

Comment: Xmacros are a technique for generating lots of boilerplate code from simple lists of items.  It can avoid reams of repeated code (similar to how a template does), and can therefore increase readability and reduce bugs.  Another advantage is they are evaluated at compile time, rather than runtime.  The downside is that the the code can be confusing, so I include LOTS of comments explaining. 
 For a better explanation, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro